# How to check string start with $ symbol and can have alphabet and positive digit

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am trying to check string which:

1. Must start from $ symbol
2. followed by $ symbol it can have alphabets and digits(no sign).
3. No Special character and space are allowed(except $ symbol in the beginning)

`is_match = re.search("^\$[a-zA-Z0-9]", word)`

**Problem I am facing**

It is accepting special characters and space in my string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backslashes in regular strings are processed by Python before the regex engine gets to see them. Use a raw string around regular expressions, generally (or double all your backslashes).

Also, your regex simply checks if there is (at least) one alphanumeric character after the dollar sign. If you want to examine the whole string, you need to create a regular expression which examines the whole string.

```
is_match = re.search(r"^\$[a-zA-Z0-9]+$", word)
```

or

```
is_match = re.search("^\\$[a-zA-Z0-9]+$", word)
```

Answer (score 3):

Modified your regex to this:

```
^\$[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

1. `^` asserts position at the start of a line
2. `\$` matches the character `$` in the beginning
3. `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` matches these characters for one or more times
4. `$` asserts position at the end of a line

**Explanation:**

1. You were basically searching for  string that started with
   `"$abc123456789"` so it didn't matter how your strings ended with. I
   just added `$` in the end to your regex which asserts position at
   the end of a line
2. It makes sure that the entire string  will only consist alphabets
   and numbers and nothing else.

Source ([run](https://ideone.com/muUigv) ):

```
    regex = r"^\$[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"
    test_str = ("$abc123     ")
    is_match = re.search(regex, test_str)
    if(is_match):
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2y2PPl/1)

Comment: Thankyou so much .Can you tell me why it was accepting special characters?

Comment: @AreebaJunaid updated my answer for better explnation